# Which is the original "L’Abbaye des morts" game?

Tags: sega-genesis, commodore-64

The game [L’Abbaye des morts](https://locomalito.com/abbaye_des_morts.php) can be found implemented for many retro and modern systems. For example:

- [Commodore 64](https://doublesidedgames.com/shop/commodore/commodore-64/abbaye-des-morts/)
- [Sega](https://megacatstudios.com/products/labbaye-des-morts)
- [ZX Spectrum](https://spectrumcomputing.co.uk/index.php?cat=96&id=30109)

It is visible that the game is implemented by different people or companies and that some of the ports are commercial. This makes me wonder which is the original game and who owns the right to it. Also, is it legal to create a commercial port for someone's else game?

Comment: _"is it legal to create a commercial port for someone's else game"_ - Not with the same name, no. I guarantee in all of those cases they either payed the copyright owner to use their IP, or more likely were hired by the copyright owner to write the port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original game is a freeware Windows game by Locomalito, written in 2010. It was intended to have the look and feel of a ZX Spectrum game.

It was then rewritten and open sourced by [MoonWatcher](https://twitter.com/MoonWatcherMD), and is under the [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.en) licence. That means it can be re-used for any purpose, including commercial. Hence for example the commercial C64 version by Double Sided Games, and an actual ZX Spectrum version by RetroWorks.